PromQl query for how long a process ran over time
Using Prometheus and Grafana, I want to show how long a windows process has been running for, in a selected time range. 
With:
time() - min by(process) (windows_process_start_time{process="foo"})

I can display this in a table for an instant type query so it only works if the process is currently running. 
I've tried changing query type to range and with different (eg. max) aggregations on the whole query but can't get it to work.


you don't need aggregation at all. min or max make no difference here. 2. To display also length of run for already finished processes, you will also need to change logic of query: time() - <start of process> won't cut it for something that stopped hour ago.


You might try something like last_over_time(timestamp(windows_process_start_time{process="foo"}) [$__range:]) - last_over_time(windows_process_start_time{process="foo"} [$__range]).
